Problem when running the android emulator for a react native project
I'm trying to start my first project with react native but when i try to run the android emulator this error shows:
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Dnd_Mark1'.
> Timeout waiting to lock build logic queue. It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
  Owner PID: 17736
  Our PID: 3636
  Owner Operation:
  Our operation:
  Lock file: D:\_React Native\Dnd_Mark1\android\.gradle\noVersion\buildLogic.lock

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5m 36s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Dnd_Mark1'. > Timeout waiting to lock build logic queue. It is currently in use by another Gradle instance. Owner PID: 17736 Our PID: 3636 Owner Operation: Our operation: Lock file: D:\_React Native\Dnd_Mark1\android\.gradle\noVersion\buildLogic.lock * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 5m 36s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I expect to open the android emulator

If you haven't, check this
